# How to Bind JSON data through Web API(Online Services) with xaml UI In Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I am developing my first application in Windows 8. I saw tutorial from Channel 9 of Windows 8 http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Store-apps-for-Absolute-Beginners-with-C-#
 I want to make a demo app where data is come through web services But I can't able to make DataSource.cs file for JSON Data Which I recieve through Web Service.

This is my JSON Data come throgh Web Services..

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Test_rom",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.1.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Jewelry",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.2.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Jackets",
        "subtitle": "All sizes available",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.3.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Dresses",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.4.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "Bags",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.5.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Watches",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.6.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "Glasses",
        "subtitle": "",
        "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.8.png"
    }
]
```

Now I want to make a Grid Template For these Group Category JSON DATA. But I am new in this field and I tried to bind this with XAML UI But I failed.

I try a lot to find some related code But All code are for windows phone 8 and i want for windows 8 Metro Application.

These are the code in XAML Where i got confuse.

```
  <Page.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="Items"
            d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=local:RootObject, CreateList=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>
```

AND

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<string,> pageState)
{
OsCatalogData os = new OsCatalogData();
os.GetJson(Constants.OscatalogMenulist, "HomePagemenu");

// TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data

this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = os.?????; 

}
```

And I am trying to develop it from so many days. Can anyone Help??
I don't want fully code But some material where can i fulfill my requirement....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

What I undersatand from your question  - you are having a problem in parsing the json data, that you want to use .Hope I will be right -

`1` => Install Newtonsoft.json nuget package. it will be used for parsing json efficiently     and very easy to use.

`2`  => Now create a RootObject Class ( Name it accordingly - it is a simple Data Parser Class ).

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string subtitle { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

`3` => Now your Json represent a List/Array of these Class Objects of What actually your json Type is List so parse it like this.

```
var groups= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(yourJson);
```

Now your groups contains your data in the form C# Class now you can use them according to your need.

Comment: I did the all thing....My question is =>  I have problem with binding the data with xaml  <Page.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            IsSourceGrouped="true"
            ItemsPath="Items"
            d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=local:RootObject, CreateList=True}}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

Answer (score 1):

Read this http://prathapk.net/consuming-web-api-in-windows-phone-8/
and this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

PS: Use "Group" and not "Groups" when you bind them. 
I hope this will help you. Got here searching for a similar problem.